# Kmeans plotting on discriminant coordinates

Tags: clustering, k-means

When you plot a kmeans model (in R) with the plotcluster() function, it plots the clusters against the axis of the 1st and 2nd discriminant components (dc).

In reading about these axis- some state the dc is not that much practical difference from the 1st and 2nd principal components. Other places seem to give a distinct difference.

Any clarifications for me?

Just want to understand what I am plotting against.

Thanks

Comment: Can you give a reference/citation/description of what are `discriminant components`? The term itself seems not to be a widely accepted one, as, say, "discriminant function" or "principal component".

Comment: my typo- discriminant coordinates.   Part of the plotcluster in R documentation- Discriminant projection plot.